# facebook sdk dont show fb-page for my domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

when I post the following code on my web site it show fb-page correctly

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/sdk/debug.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" 
data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-width="500" data-height="600">
    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">facebookc</a></blockquote></div>

</body>
</html>
```

However when I change the domain to mine it display a blank page, why ?

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/my-domain" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-width="500" data height="600">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/my-domain/" class="fb-xfbml parse-ignore">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/my-domain">my-domain</a></blockquote></div>
```

needless to say that https://www.facebook.com/my-domain works correctly

Thanks

Comment: Your page is likely access-restricted in some way. As the documentation for the Page plugin states, it only works with _fully_ public pages.

Comment: (And FYI, that is not a “domain”, but simply a page username.)

Comment: there is no Alcohol/age/state restriction on the setting
should I add something to the "Server IP Whitelist" ?
Can I get any error/log regarding the reason  ?

Comment: No, server IP whitelist has nothing to do with that. // You can easily check this in Graph API Explorer, try and make a request for your page name, using an app access token (you must choose one of your own app ids from the dropdown first) - if the page is restricted in any way, you will get an “Unsupported GET request” error.